# Unable to display input values in console

Tags: javascript

I have entered `e.preventDefault` but after this, web page got refresh and
JavaScript `<script>` is added in body.

```js
function myCode(){
       const form = document.getElementById('form');
       const names = document.getElementById('names');
       const password = document.getElementById('password');
       form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
              e.preventDefault(); 
              console.log('form submitted');
              console.log(names.value);
              console.log(password.value);
 });
}
```

Comment: Can you show your html?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn about the rules of the site as well as [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Is `myCode` ever called?

Answer (score -1):

Welcome! I just put your code together and can't see any error. You need to post your full code in order to get some advice.

```js
function myCode() {
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const names = document.getElementById('names');
  const password = document.getElementById('password');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('form submitted');
    console.log(names.value);
    console.log(password.value);
  });

}

myCode();
```

```html
<form id="form" action="">
  <input id="names">
  <input id="password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You should just wait for the OP to provide more details before answering, this answer currently is only asking for details which shouldnt be posted as an answer